# How to get Container object from LifecycleEventArgs of postLoad in Entity?

Tags: php, symfony, entity, containers, symfony-2.6

I'm trying to inject the Container object (which is available in controllers) into an Entity using `postLoad` `lifecycleCallbacks`. The argument to the `postLoad` method is `LifecycleEventArgs`. I could see the container property (which I want to retrieve) in `EventManager` of `LifecycleEventArgs` according to the dump output, but it seems to be a private property and there is no `getContainer()` method in `EventManager`. The below is my code.

service.yml

```
services:
    ibw.jobeet.entity.job.container_aware:
        class: Ibw\JobeetBundle\Entity\Job
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
```

Ibw\JobeetBundle\Entity\Job.php

```
<?php
namespace Ibw\JobeetBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

use Ibw\JobeetBundle\Utils\Jobeet;

/**
 * Job
 */
class Job
{
    //....
    /**
     * @var Container
     */
    protected $container;

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        $eventManager = $entityManager->getEventManager();
        echo '<pre>';
        \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($eventManager, 3);

        // want to get $eventManager->container here

        exit;
    }
    //....
}
```

Is there any other way to retrieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use setter-injection which result in a call to a predefined method (`setContainer()` in this case) with the container as an argument upon creation of the listener service:

```
services:
    ibw.jobeet.entity.job.container_aware:
        class: Your\Bundle\Doctrine\Event\Listener\JobListener
        calls:
            - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
```

Now the container is injected into the constructor of your listener class:

```
namespace Your\Bundle\Doctrine\Event\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class JobListener
{
     /** @var ContainerInterface */
     protected $container;

     /** 
      * @param ContainerInterface @container
      */
     public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container)
     {
          $this->container = $container;
     }

     public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
     {
         $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
         // do something with your entity here i.e.
         $entity->setFoo($this->container->getParameter('foo'));
```

This is just an example. Please consider injecting only the services you really need - instead of injecting the container itself. You will be rewarded with better testability and performance.

Comment: I got this error `The service "ibw.jobeet.entity.job.container_aware" has a dependency on a non-existent service "container".`

Comment: I found that `["@service_container"]` is the correct usage.

Comment: `@service_container` is correct - sorry hacked it down quickly ... updated the answer for future readers.

Comment: Sometimes, `postLoad` is not running for the repository, in this case "Job" repository. I think `postLoad` is invoked when the repository is loaded. Under some circumstances, the repository is not loaded, for example, for the route `/job/new`.