# Symfony 3 error when injecting entity manager into event listener

Tags: php, symfony, events, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm

I have an event listener that sets up some session variables and also checks if a visitor has set a type of shopping cart on a previous visit and shows its details on the front end.

The event was working fine till a tried to inject the entity manager, from which I need to use some setters/getters on the Visitor entity.

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479180/how-to-get-container-object-from-lifecycleeventargs-of-postload-in-entity) but ended up with the same issue of 'string given' instead of the object.

The error it produces is:

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to AppBundle\EventListener\InitializerListener::onKernelRequest() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, string given

This is the code:]

services.yml

```
  app.initializer_listener:
  class: AppBundle\EventListener\InitializerListener
  arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
  tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelRequest }
```

AppBundle\EventListener\IniatilizerListener

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use UsedBundle\Entity\Visitor;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class InitializerListener
{
private $event;
private $em;

public function onKernelRequest( FilterControllerEvent $event, EntityManager $em )
{   
    $visitor = new Visitor();

    $this->em = $em;

    $route = $event->getRequest()->get('_route');
    if ($event->isMasterRequest() && '_wdt' !== $route ) {
        $session = $event->getRequest()->getSession();
        $cookies = $event->getRequest()->cookies;
        $this->sessionInit( $session, $cookies );
        //$this->visitorInit( $session, $cookies, $visitor );
        //$em->persist($visitor);
        //$em->flush();
    }
}

private function sessionInit( $session, $cookies )
{
    $session->set('active', time() );
    $session->has('page_ct') ? $session->set('page_ct', $session->get('page_ct') + 1 ): $session->set('page_ct', 1 );
}

private function visitorInit($session, $cookies, $visitor)
{
   //visitor setup/shopping cart here
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should inject the EntityManager into the class instead of the function? (Not really familiar with sf3 but that's what i'd do in sf2.8)

```
class InitializerListener
{
    private $event;
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest( FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {   
       ...
    }

}
```

Comment: an obvious follow up question: why can one inject FilterControllerEvent into the function but not $em?

Comment: Because it is not injected. It's just a default parameter which will always be added by the EventDispatcher when a listener function is called. Think of it like an Event is announced the Dispatcher takes the Event and figures out which Listeners should be notified calls the given method and hands over the Event which may contain further data related to the event (in Doctrine lifecycle events for example the LifecycleArgs event object which contains the entity). For more info you should check https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html#creating-and-dispatching-an-event